# Efficient Drools evalution for element in array or collection

Tags: java, drools

Using Drools 3.0.6 (old, I know), what is an efficient evaluation for finding a fact in a known, fixed and quite large array or collection (the inverse of contains, i.e. "is contained in").
Using an OR series of normal "equals" results in StackOverflowError as the array/collection can contain a few thousand entries, as the Drools binary operator evaluation is recursive.

We have a single value fact and an array of values to match. The current "code" looks like this:

```
$f: Fact(name="TheFact", $data)
eval(!($data.equals("1") || $data.equals("2") || $data.equals("3") ... ))
```

for a large number of fixed values (1,2,3, ...). I'm looking for something more like "$data in (1,2,3, ...)".

Comment: Are you able to paste a code sample?

Comment: We have a single value fact and an array of values to match. The current "code" looks like this:

$f: Fact(name="TheFact", $data)
eval(!($data.equals("1") || $data.equals("2") || $data.equals("3") ... ))

for a large number of fixed values (1,2,3, ...). I'm looking for something more like "$data in (1,2,3, ...)".

Comment: Ouch, added to the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you need to (or it is more readable to) put some of the evaluation into the object itself.  Then you can reduce the eval statements to sometihng like `eval(!$f.isInRange(1, 200))`